# Sublime code folding of comments (as in Ace)

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

In Cloud9 (based on the Ace editor) I can define arbitrary code folding regions within comments, for example:

```
// Descriptor {
function() {

    // Code

}
// }
```

Folds to:

```
// Descriptor {<->}
```

[Try it here to see what I mean](http://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html).

Is there an existing way to replicate this in Sublime?

Answer (score 4):

Select the block of code and Hit "Ctrl + Shift + [" to fold.
To unfold place pointer before the folded block and hit  "Ctrl + Shift + ]"

here's an youtube video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80UUPMUAP-g

Answer (score 0):

From http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-code-folding/

> To fold a block, place your cursor anywhere within the block you want
>   to fold. Now you just hit the folding keys to collapse that block.
>
> ```
> Command + Option + [
> ```

The thing you will have to remember is that Sublime Text's folding mechanism is dependent on code intention levels and not scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use `CMD+K+1` to fold at level 1, `CMD+K+2` for level 2, etc
`CMD+K+J` will unfold all
`CMD+OPT+[` will fold / hide the current level of indendation, `CMD+OPT+]` will unfold any of the yellow rectangle symbols at the end of a line

Answer (score 0):

Comment folding works if content is a bit deeper. Instead of this

```
/*
line 1
line 2
line 3
*/
```

use:

```
/*
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
*/
```