# How to configure SyntaxFold plugin in SublimeText to fold perl pod comment

Tags: perl, sublimetext3

I'm trying to configure my SublimeText to create folding markers for Perl POD (Plain Old Documentation) comments. How do I do this using the SyntaxFold plugin (https://github.com/jamalsenouci/sublimetext-syntaxfold)?

I have look at this [Sublime code folding of comments (as in Ace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902305/sublime-code-folding-of-comments-as-in-ace) , but I prefer something creates folding markers for POD comments.